# How to upgrade Arduino UnoR3 clock

Tags: arduino-uno, timing, oscillator-clock

A little background:

I need to generate a 40KHz frequency as accurately as possible.

(One of my other posts is here: 
[Stable frequency generation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/stable-frequency-generation))

My code is solid- I'm using an Uno R3 and generating the most accurate frequency I can at this point. The only way to get a more accurate frequency is to upgrade the ceramic resonator to a crystal oscillator.

So, my over-arching question is: How do I actually upgrade the ceramic resonator to a crystal oscillator?

Things I'm considering are:

Is it worth it to actually upgrade my Uno R3 - and is it even possible? Is there a clone that drives the ATMega328p with a crystal oscillator that I could use instead? Is there simply just a better model for this application?

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to take an ATmega328 chip and wire it up on it's own.  There are even instructions on the Arduino site on how to do it.  Take a look at http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone .

You could even pull the 328 out of the Uno, add the crystal and a few caps and then program it with the Uno board.  I've done this a few times myself and it worked just fine for my needs.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a bare chip as I'm using a 12v supply to power the Uno and utilizing the onboard 5v for some other circuitry.

Comment: A 7805 voltage regulator would be easy to add to that circuit to give you a nice 5v to power the atmega and any other circuitry you have. They are relatively cheap and plentiful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Arduino R3 reference design, it should have a crystal! But in practice it seems that the manufacturers are cutting corners and using a resonator because it is cheaper. I don't like your chances of fitting an xtal instead of a resonator. Unless you are a soldering expert and have suitable facilities, the most likely outcome is a dead board.

If your board has the MCU chip in a socket, you could bend the xtal pins so they don't go into the socket and solder a xtal and a couple capacitors to them. Not exactly a production line solution, but it will be fine if you just want a one-off - and anyone reasonably at home with a soldering iron could do it.

Freetronics (an Australian company) make a R3 compatable with xtals for both processors. These are very well made (I own two), and have a prototyping area as well. Downside is the higher cost. See http://www.freetronics.com.au/products/eleven#.VT3F-PCo1BA

Comment: The eleven may have its LEDs on the edge (where they belong), but the reset button is still in the middle of the board, which is *not* R3 compatible, and won't be reachable with a shield on top. Besides, two identical crystals this close together is kinda stupid. They could have done with one crystal and use a buffer to bring the clock to the other microcontroller. And yes, AUD 40 is expensive.

Comment: @JorisGroosman The site I pointed to is AUD 29.00 - a bit less but still quite expensive (and they are out of stock)

Comment: @kiwiron I do like the idea of slightly bending the pins as a one off solution... Although the Eleven would work perfectly if I could find one. Without trying to get off topic from my original question, can I run my code on a Freeduino? (I would be able to solder a crystal into the kit).